# creating new column based on condition (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe where one of the columns, "deals" is a TRUE/FALSE boolean. I want to create a new column that populates 1 when the "deals" column is True, and 0 when the "deals" columns is False.

I tried the following code but it's giving me all zeros.

```
df['madedeal'] = np.where(df['deal']=='True', 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `astype(int)` which converts True to 1 and False to 0 (no need for `np.where` here):

```
df['madedeal'] = df['deal'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare with `True`, not `"True"` because `"True"` is `str`.

Also, it would be more recommended to use `is` when you compare with `True` or `False` rather than `==` ([PEP 8: E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'deal': [True, False, True, False]
})

df['madedeal'] = np.where(df['deal'] is True, 1, 0)
# df['madedeal'] = np.where(df['deal'], 1, 0 # This also works as @sammywemmy commented.

print(df)

#    deal  madedeal
#0   True         1
#1  False         0
#2   True         1
#3  False         0
```

Comment: you don't need the True, since that check is implicit ``np.where(df['deal'], 1, 0)``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks for the comment. I added your solution in the code so that other people can see.